# teaching calculus question: request for thoughts on limits and indeterminate forms

Tags: calculus

seems to me that on a first semester, approx-typical calculus course most limits of functions  at points of discontinuity are revealed quickly by plugging in the limit value and drawing one of the famous 7 indeterminate forms.

This forms an intimate relationship between limits and indeterminate forms, almost to the points that we could [i think should] sell limits on the sole basis that they cure indeterminate forms. whatever point of view you prefer, I would guess that most of us see the relationship between limits and indeterminate form as essential and of utmost importance, yet I see so many textbooks doing limits in chapter one and indeterminate forms in chapter 10 seems to me a blatant lapse in good judgment, yet so many textbooks do it.. leaving me to wonder if there is something I am missing here..  any thoughts are appreciated...

Comment: What are the seven famous indeterminate forms? Where I come from, indeterminate forms were hardly ever mentioned, they certainly got no systematic treatment.

Comment: I think that in a "general purpose" calculus course, it is good to get to applications as quickly as possible.

Comment: @DanielFischer same where i come from.. but i'm suggesting they should be treated more systematically and alongside with limits they go hand in hand..  $\frac{0}{0} \quad   \frac{\infty}{\infty}\quad  \infty - \infty\quad  
 0 \cdot \infty \quad  0^0\quad \infty^0 \quad  1^{\infty}$

Comment: $0/0$, $\infty/\infty$,$\infty-\infty$ and $0 \infty$ I introduce early in the semester because this is precisely the problem of calculating limits. Most of the time, you either plug in the point or do algebra to refine one of these to continuous expression and/or a manifestly divergent $1/0$-type form. Moreover, I sell limits precisely as you suggest. They are exactly constructed to extend past algebra to treat indeterminant forms. Furthermore, this is precisely the interesting case since the tangent problem is by it's very nature always $0/0$. Stick to your guns. Ignore the silly text.

Comment: There are other indeterminate forms besides these seven; it seems silly to sell them as "the 7 indeterminate forms" as if they were the seven wonders or something.  E.g. $\sin \infty$.

Comment: wow @JamesS.Cook i am not alone!!!

Comment: Personally, I would think that they aren't taught (directly) along side with the introduction to limits as it could give off the false impression that limits matter at the point we are taking the limit, and not values close to the point.

Comment: thank you Goos to be fair i did not say there are seven.. I said there are 7 famous ones.. perhaps you like a different additive thats no problem with me.. we can call them anything you like..

Comment: thank you @AndréNicolas thank you